# Using Variables to define a range in find mode

Tags: excel, vba

I'm pretty sure this is possible to do but, i have a Variable "DataRowStart" which is assigned a values by the user through an input box, e.g. "A" is there a way to use that variable to define the start of an search? I need this as the location of the data search will change from use to use.

I currently have this line of code for the search;

```
LastRowNumber = Range("DataRowStart:DataRowStart").Find(What:="", after:=Range(Cells(DataColumn, 1)), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

And whenever i run the code i get

> Method 'Range' of Object'_ Global failed

error.

I defined the variable as a `Global DataRowStart as String` in the macro that runs this.

I found that this was the best solution as this part of the code is run in a User Form.

Is someone able to point me in the right direction to solve this issue?

Many thanks

Mark

Comment: is "A" you are getting through an `InputBox` suppose to be a `Column` or `Row` ?

Comment: I was expecting a full range reference like "A1"

Comment: `DataRowStart` is part of a literal string, not a variable.

Comment: @ShaiRado yes the "A" is meant to det which column is serached for data

Comment: @QHarr If i swap out `DataRowStart` for A the program runs with no issue

Comment: @braX what do you mean by that, pretty new to VBA dont really understand what you mean, sorry

Comment: @CptGoodar look at the answer below. That's what I meant.

Comment: @braX, thank, answer hadnt loaded by then :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the variable `DataRowStart` outside the `"`.

Change:

```
LastRowNumber = Range("DataRowStart:DataRowStart")
```

to

```
LastRowNumber = Range(DataRowStart & ":" & DataRowStart)
```

And also:

```
Range(Cells(1, DataColumn)
```

To:

```
Range(DataColumn & 1)
```

Comment: when i run this code i now get "Application-defined or object error" which is think is from the `Range(Cells(DataColumn,1))` section. Would i be right in thinking this? IGNOR THIS MISTYPED A LETTER

Comment: Unfortunetly, when i run this code, after this letter mistype i still get the saame Metho'Range... error

Comment: @CptGoodar yes, you are correct. see edited code. I changed it according to `DataColumn` represents a `Column`.

Comment: That solved it and is now working as intend. Thank you very much,